# Finding Two Bases Which When Converted to Base 10 Are Equal

Tags: java, c++, math, numbers, digit

I have a very challenging problem here today. I cannot think of a way to solve it.

Given 6 numbers as input: a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, find 2 numbers X and Y such that a1 * x^2 + a2 ^ x + a3 = b1 * y^2 + b2 * y + b3. X and Y must be between 10 and 15000 inclusive.

What I have tried:

I have tried all X values from 10-15000 and all Y values from 10-15000, and checked if they satisfied the equation. However, this method is extremely slow. Does anyone have a faster solution? Thanks.

My Bad Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = 10; i <= 15000; i++) {
        for (int j = 10; j <= 15000; j++) {
            if (conv(a, i) == conv(b, j)) {
                cout << i << " " << j << endl;
                j = 20000;
                i = 20000;
            }
        }
    }
}
long long conv(int x, int b) {
long long ans = 0;
int count = 0;
while (x) {
    int y = x % 10;
    ans += y * poww(b, count);
    count++;
    x /= 10;
}
return ans;
}
long long poww(int x, int y) {
long long ans = 1;
while (y != 0) {
    ans *= x;
    y--;
}
return ans;
}
```

Comment: We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Apparently your fast solution is to go to SO ? What did you try ?

Comment: Should we show as much effort as you have shown?

Comment: I have been thinking for an hour and I only have thought of one solution.

Comment: Just FYI, the "base 10" isn't really part of the problem.  What you're looking for is, given six numbers as input (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3), is to find positive integers X and Y such that a1*X^2 + a2*X + a3 = b1*Y^2 + b2*Y + b3.  I don't know if that helps--I'm not seeing an obvious approach.

Comment: Thanks ajb, I changed my problem so it's less confusing.

Comment: Can you show us the "extremely slow" code that you wrote, so we may find opportunity to improve it?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, I have posted my code on there. I am sure it's the wrong approach though. Also, the problem states that X and Y must be above 10.

Comment: Hang on, I am in the process of adding code.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  There is actual code to be seen.

Comment: OK, I thought of something.  For each X, compute the value of what the number would be in that base.  If the value is V, then you must have b1*Y^2 + b2*Y + b3 = V, and you can use the quadratic formula to see if there are any integer solutions > 10.  Since this is only a single loop and not a double loop, it will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I actually managed to solve this problem before someone posted an answer, but thanks! I love all of your replies and thank you for spending time to help me. If you're interested, my solution was the same with the double for loops, but the inner for loop went from 0 until i, instead of 0 to 15000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this might be a good occassion to exercise writing some Java code and came up with the following solution. On my system it gives the solution to the two numbers 419 and 792 (as you wrote in an earlier edit of your question the result should be Base X: 47 Base Y: 35) in 1 ms.

The code just uses some smart brute force :).

[See it running online.](http://ideone.com/naMenH)

```
public class TwoBases {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long beg = System.nanoTime();
        solve(419, 792);
        System.out.println("Time needed to calculate: "+(System.nanoTime()-beg)/1000000.0 + "ms");
    }

    public static void solve(int a, int b) {
        int[] aDigits = new int[3];
        int[] bDigits = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            aDigits[2 - i] = (a / (int) Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
            bDigits[2 - i] = (b / (int) Math.pow(10, i)) % 10;
        }
        for (int x = 10; x <= 15000; x++) {
            int numBaseX = digitsToBase10(aDigits, x);
            int y = 10;
            while (y <= 15000) {
                int numBaseY = digitsToBase10(bDigits, y);
                if (numBaseX == numBaseY) {
                    System.out.println("Base X: " + x + " Base Y: " + y);
                    return;
                } else if (numBaseY > numBaseX) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Nothing found");
    }

    public static int digitsToBase10(int[] digits, int b) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            res += digits[i] * (int) Math.pow(b, digits.length - 1 - i);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to thank you for this! THANKS